# MariaDB / File Key Management Encryption: Syntax error at keyfile

Tags: encryption, mariadb

I try to enable the data-at-rest-encryption on mariadb (10.4.6, under Windows 10 Pro), I followed [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/) instructions, and I have these lines in my.ini:

```
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = E:/MariaDB_10_Test/keyfile
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CBC
```

But it does not work, everytime I get these three lines in my log:

```
mysqld.exe: Syntax error at /MariaDB_10_Test/keyfile line 1, column 1
Plugin 'file_key_management' init function returned error.
Plugin 'file_key_management' registration as a ENCRYPTION failed.
```

The keyfile itself will be found, otherwise I get an 'file not found'-Exception. And the content of the file is, I assume, also ok, per line an integer and a key, splitted by an semicolon. I also have tried the same keyfile from the instructions (and another one from another site), with same result. What do I wrong?

Comment: Check `keyfile`, it seems a problem of some hidden character or another syntax problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ... the keyfile has to be in ANSI format. I created it with Notepad++ in another (standard) format, after converting to ANSI it worked immediatly. That's why I got the same error with the sample keys from other websites; I always copied it in the same keyfile.

Thanks to wchiquito, who gave me the decisive hint.